# Reset seq increment if seq.nextval is lower than the max id value

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Writing a stored procedure that will insert records into a table.  I am having an issue with setting the `seq.nextval` value.  In the  table  am inserting into, it appears that at times the max id value in the table is higher than the value indicated for the `nextval`.

```
SELECT TABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL AS CASE_ID
FROM DUAL;
```

> CASE_ID
>   1015

```
SELECT MAX(CASE_ID) AS CASE_ID
FROM CASE_TABLE;
```

> CASE_ID
>   2015

I need to check what the `nextval` is for the table and then compare to the Maximum value of the ID field, if the `nextval value is lower than the Max id value, I need to increment the`nextval` value until it is higher than the max id value by 1.

New to Oracle's SQL Developer tool, I've been researching how to do this, but can't find an approach. Does anyone have any idea's to share?

Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: Do you need to do this in a single query? Or can you use some procedure or function?

Comment: Hello Saghir, This will be in a stored proc.  Each time it is run, it will need to make this evaluation before inserting the nextval as the id value for the record being inserted.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear to me, how you face the result described. But I would recommend you to play around with the sequence. To reset it for example:

```
alter sequence seq_nameincrement by 124;
select seq_name.nextval from dual;
alter sequence seq_name increment by 1;
```

Also, I would recommend you to see [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php) and [that one](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1119633817597) arcticles.

Comment: Thanks for the ref links xacinay!  I'll take a look at them. :D

Answer (score 0):

Here it works:

```
select max(pk) y from sometable;

select seq.currval x from dual;
# or
select seq.nextval x from dual;

DECLARE 
   l_val NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
   FOR i IN 1..<y-x>
   LOOP 
      l_val := sometable.NEXTVAL; 
   END LOOP; 
END;
```

`ORA-32793: cannot alter a system-generated sequence` could be raised by the following.

```
alter sequence FORMS_SQ increment by 1 minvalue 0
```